# Run SQL script file with multiple complex queries using AMAZON datapipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I have just created an account on Amazon AWS and I am going to use DATAPIPELINE to schedule my queries. Is it possible to run multiple complex SQL queries from .sql file using SQLACTIVITY of data pipeline?

My overall objective is to process the raw data from REDSHIFT/s3 using sql queries from data pipeline and save it to s3. Is it the feasible way to go?

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you plan on moving the data from Redshift to S3, you need to do an `UNLOAD` command found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Answer (score 0):

The input of your sql queries will be a single DATA Node and Output will be a  single data file. Data pipeline provide only one "Select query" field in which you will write your extraction/transformation query. I don't think there are any use case of multiple queries file.

However if you want to make your pipeline configurable ,you can make your pipeline configurable by adding "parameters" and values objects in your pipeline definition JSON.

```
{
   "objects":[
  {
     "selectQuery":"#{myRdsSelectQuery}"
  }
  ],
  "parameters":[
  { 
     "description":"myRdsSelectQuery",
     "id":"myRdsSelectQuery",
     "type":"String"
  }
  ],
   "values":{
      "myRdsSelectQuery":"Select Query"
 }
}
```

If you want to execute and schedule multiple sql script , you can do with ShellCommandActivity.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to execute a script with multiple insert statements with following AWS datapipeline configuration:

```
    {
      "id": "ExecuteSqlScript",
      "name": "ExecuteSqlScript",
      "type": "SqlActivity",
      "scriptUri": "s3://mybucket/inserts.sql",
      "database": { "ref": "rds_mysql" },
      "runsOn": { "ref": "Ec2Instance" }
    }, {
      "id": "rds_mysql",
      "name": "rds_mysql",
      "type": "JdbcDatabase",
      "username": "#{myUsername}",
      "*password": "#{*myPassword}",
      "connectionString" : "#{myConnStr}",
      "jdbcDriverClass": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
      "jdbcProperties": ["allowMultiQueries=true","zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"]
    },
```

It is important to allow the MySql driver to execute multiple queries with `allowMultiQueries=true` and the script s3 path is provided by `scriptUri`